# Conditional formatting an area anchored to a criteria cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I would like the following result:

Number of cells (here 3) highlighted below the cell contains TRUE

[image: Number of cells (here 3) highlighted below the cell contains TRUE]

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no VBA needed:

1. Go to cell D4 and select it (otherwise the provided formula will not work).
2. Add a conditional formatting rule (formula) and add this as formula:

   [image]

   ```
   =OR(IFERROR(D1=TRUE,FALSE),IFERROR(D2=TRUE,FALSE),IFERROR(D3=TRUE,FALSE),IFERROR(D4=TRUE,FALSE))
   ```
3. Save the rule and copy format [image] of D4 into your desired range. The result will be like below:

   *Note that `WAHR` means `TRUE` (sorry for german screenshot)*
   [image]

Comment: I am still trying to understand why the formula works in a mirrored way, but works :) Thank you.

Little added info. How do I modify it, if I would like to put 0 (value from a formula) in the place of TRUE?

Comment: I got it:
Applies to: =$F$5:$EI$18 Formula: (highlights 4 below and 7 above)
=OR
(
IFERROR(AND(F5=0;F5<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F4=0;F4<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F3=0;F3<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F2=0;F2<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F1=0;F1<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F6=0;F6<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F7=0;F7<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F8=0;F8<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F9=0;F9<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F10=0;F10<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F11=0;F11<>"");FALSE);
IFERROR(AND(F12=0;F12<>"");FALSE)
)

Comment: Thank you very much again, your kick helped me a lot :) Big hug